# how to troubleshoot queryset requirement in django form

Tags: python, django

I'm working a Django 2.0 website, and trying to build out a django form:

forms.py:

```
class NewMemberstatusform(forms.Form):
    rank = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Rank.objects.all(), widget=forms.ModelChoiceField(
        attrs={
        'class':'form-control'
        }
    ))
    unit = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Unit.objects.all(), widget=forms.ModelChoiceField(
        attrs={
        'class':'form-control'
        }
    ))
    activate = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YesNo.YESNO_CHOICES, label="Enable Member to see their information", widget=forms.ChoiceField(
        attrs={
        'class':'form-control'
        }
    ))
```

My problem is that it does not compile correctly.

I receive this error saying I'm missing the queryset in the rank field, but as you can see, it's clearly in the class.  What am I missing?  Thanks

```
    class NewMemberstatusform(forms.Form):
  File "/Users/sinistersparrow/PycharmProjects/ifthqcom/app_svcrecord/forms.py", line 126, in NewMemberstatusform
    'class':'form-control'
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing `forms.ModelChoiceField` to the widget keyword argument, and that's the instantiation that's causing the error. You probably want to pass `forms.Select` instead:

```
class NewMemberstatusform(forms.Form):
    rank = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=models.Rank.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    )
    unit = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=models.Unit.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    )
    activate = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=YesNo.YESNO_CHOICES,
        label="Enable Member to see their information",
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    )
```

Comment: This works. I'll have to read more up on the forms class.  Now I have another problem....but I'll make that a new question so you can get more points.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try using the import statement for your models:

```
from <myapp>.models import Rank, Unit

class NewMemberstatusform(forms.Form):
    rank = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Rank.objects.all(), widget=forms.ModelChoiceField(
        attrs={
        'class':'form-control'
        }
    ))
    unit = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Unit.objects.all(), widget=forms.ModelChoiceField(
        attrs={
        'class':'form-control'
        }
    ))
....
```